# How to create a custom meta box field in category?

Tags: categories

I'm creating a website, and I want to associate images every time I create a new category? Does anyone know how I give this option to the user through this menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this code to **functions.php** file

```
add_action ( 'category_add_form_fields', '___add_form_field_term_meta_text' );
function ___add_form_field_term_meta_text() {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field custom_image_upload">
        <label for="tag-description">File Upload</label>
        <img src="" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:0;display:none;" />
        <a title="Set listing image" href="javascript:;" id="upload_listing_image_button" id="set-listing-image" data-uploader_title="Choose an image" data-uploader_button_text="Set listing image">Set listing image</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="upload_listing_image" name="_listing_cover_image" value="" />
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action ( 'category_edit_form_fields', '___edit_form_field_term_meta_text' );
function ___edit_form_field_term_meta_text($term) {
    $image_id = get_term_meta ( $term->term_id, '_listing_cover_image', true );
    if( empty ( $image_id ) ) {
        $display_none = 'display:none;';
        $upload_link  = '<a title="Set listing image" href="javascript:;" id="upload_listing_image_button" id="set-listing-image" data-uploader_title="Choose an image" data-uploader_button_text="Set listing image">Set listing image</a>';
    } else {
        $display_none = '';
        $upload_link  = '<a title="Set listing image" href="javascript:;" id="remove_listing_image_button" data-uploader_title="Choose an image" data-uploader_button_text="Set listing image">Remove listing image</a>';
    }
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field custom_image_upload">
        <th scope="row"><label for="term-meta-text"><?php _e ( 'File Upload', 'text_domain' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src ( $image_id )[ 0 ]; ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:0;<?php echo $display_none; ?>" />
            <?php echo $upload_link; ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="upload_listing_image" name="_listing_cover_image" value="<?php echo $image_id; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action ( 'edit_category', '___save_term_meta_text' );
add_action ( 'create_category', '___save_term_meta_text' );
function ___save_term_meta_text($term_id) {
    if( isset ( $_POST[ '_listing_cover_image' ] ) ) {
        $image_id = (int) $_POST[ '_listing_cover_image' ];
        update_term_meta ( $term_id, '_listing_cover_image', $image_id );
    }
}

add_filter ( 'manage_edit-category_columns', '___edit_term_columns' );
function ___edit_term_columns($columns) {
    $columns[ '__term_meta_text' ] = __ ( 'Image', 'text_domain' );
    return $columns;
}

// RENDER COLUMNS (render the meta data on a column)
add_filter ( 'manage_category_custom_column', '___manage_term_custom_column', 10, 3 );
function ___manage_term_custom_column($out, $column, $term_id) {
    if( '__term_meta_text' === $column ) {
        $image_id = get_term_meta ( $term_id, '_listing_cover_image', true );
        if( ! empty ( $image_id ) ) {
            $out = '<span class="term-meta-text-block" style="" ><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src ( $image_id )[ 0 ] . '"style="width:50px;height:50px;border:0;" /></div>';
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

add following code in registered admin javascript file which is enqueue via **admin_enqueue_scripts**

ex. mine is **admin-script.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Uploading files
    var file_frame;

    jQuery.fn.upload_listing_image = function (button) {
        var button_id = button.attr('id');
        var field_id = button_id.replace('_button', '');

        // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
        if (file_frame) {
            file_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Create the media frame.
        file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: jQuery(this).data('uploader_title'),
            button: {
                text: jQuery(this).data('uploader_button_text'),
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        // When an image is selected, run a callback.
        file_frame.on('select', function () {
            var attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            jQuery("#" + field_id).val(attachment.id);
            jQuery(".custom_image_upload img").attr('src', attachment.url);
            jQuery('.custom_image_upload img').show();
            jQuery('#' + button_id).attr('id', 'remove_listing_image_button');
            jQuery('#remove_listing_image_button').text('Remove listing image');
        });

        // Finally, open the modal
        file_frame.open();
    };

    jQuery('.custom_image_upload').on('click', '#upload_listing_image_button', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.fn.upload_listing_image(jQuery(this));
    });

    jQuery('.custom_image_upload').on('click', '#remove_listing_image_button', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#upload_listing_image').val('');
        jQuery('.custom_image_upload img').attr('src', '');
        jQuery('.custom_image_upload img').hide();
        jQuery(this).attr('id', 'upload_listing_image_button');
        jQuery('#upload_listing_image_button').text('Set listing image');
    });
    jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (settings.data.indexOf('add-tag') > -1) {
            jQuery(document).find('#remove_listing_image_button').trigger('click');
        }
    });

});
```

you should get result like this

[image]

[image]